# Не могу исправить ошибку в командной строке

Tags: python, cmd

я устанавливаю пакеты с помощью pip и ошибка

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy Failed to build numpy

я так понял, нужно установить visual c++ build tools, но я не намерен его устанавливать, так как оно просто сожрет мое свободное место на диске.
как исправить эту проблему не устанавливая это?
я также читал как исправить это, на английском стаковерфлов, но мне не помогли другие варианты...
Мне хотелось бы также узнать как можно устанавливать что-то не с помощью pip на windows 10

Answer (score 0):

хз, visual c++ нужен для компиляции библиотек. Там изначально качается исходный код, и из него тут же собирается. Если ругается на visual build tools, то, извините, качайте их, вам без них никак.

Answer (score 0):

> Мне хотелось бы также узнать как можно устанавливать что-то не с помощью pip на windows 10

Тут два варианта - либо качать готовые **exe** файлы (если это что-то в духе *youtube-dl*), либо качать **.whl** файлы и далее `pip install .\requirement.whl`. А уже за ними - идите на *Github*, либо по питонячим сайтам).

Comment: Я решил скачать файлы whl и распоковать их, но пока что это идет долго